# why assignment operator returns ref not pointer?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I saw some q&a on SO about the Big-Three and copy-and-swap.
Indeed, I learned some new stuff, but there's one thing I don't quite understand.

Why does the operator= return a reference not a pointer?

Comment: WhY *would* it return a pointer?

Comment: Why would you like to return a pointer?

Comment: It's not that I would like to return a pointer, I just wonder why pick ref not pointer.

Comment: Because you won't be able to write stuff like `a = b = c` then.

Comment: You're free to return anything you like, but the only sensible choices are (a) return a reference to behave like the built-in operator, or (b) return nothing to keep things simple. What would you do with a pointer?

Comment: @Alcott: Try to think of advantages of either approach. The first advantage of the *reference* approach is that it is consistent with fundamental types (integers, floating point, even pointers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from returning a pointer if you'd like (though, I don't see why), but if you want to mimick the behaviour of the integral types in c++ you return a reference.

Comment: @Alcott: The language tries to make user defined types as similar to fundamental types as possible, and this is just one more example. If you are allowed to do `i = j = k` with any fundamental type, you should also be able to do it with a user defined type that overloads `operator=`. Returning a pointer would just make things messier and inconsistent: `i = *(j = k)` would be *weird* to parse...

Answer (score 3):

Why should it, what good would a pointer be? Returning a reference allows you to say `x = y = z;` which a pointer wouldn't, and generally lets you use `x = y` as an lvalue of the same type as `x`.

You're free to overload any assignment operator you like, but the standard practice of returning a reference to the object itself is very useful.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment operator sets the operators left hand side equal to its right hand side, so conceptually the types of lhs and rhs should match. If your assignment operator takes a reference as its parameter, it ought to return a reference:

```
Foo &operator=(const Foo &f);
```

It would be downright weird to write:

```
Foo *operator=(const Foo &f);   // this is weird because type of lhs != type of rhs
```

Now, you could provide a version of operator=() that assigns one Foo* to another:

```
Foo *operator=(const Foo *f);
```

but the "big three" or "rule of three" doesn't say anything about assigning pointers. The "rule" says that if you override any of {destructor, assignment operator, copy constructor}, you'll probably need to override all of them because they should all deal with the same set of ivars. But that's when you're assigning one *object* to another. Assigning one *pointer* to another is usually the same no matter the type of the pointer.

Think what would happen if you used the Foo* version of the assignment operator in place of the reference version: you'd have no way to set two pointers to point to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

Returning a pointer would mean that instead of writing

```
a = b = c;
```

you would have to write

```
*(a = b) = c;
```

which is ugly and also contrdicts normal C/C++ usage.

Comment: Don't you mean `a = *(b = c)`?

Comment: That would be `a = *(b = c);` to have the same effect. Which strengthens your argument - it's not just ugly and unexpected, it's also easier to use incorrectly.